# How to plot a distribution graph comparing subsets of different DataFrames

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn, distribution

I have two DataFrames for which I would like to compare the distribution / density of a specific item in each Dataframe.

For instance if I want to compare 'Amy' and 'Andrew':

```
df1
        | Count |
ID     
Amy     |   5   |
Chris   |   4   |
Gabe    |   2   |
```

```
df2
        | Count |
ID     
Andrew  |   2   |
Chloe   |   3   |
Georgia |   1   |
```

I have calculate the following but I am now unsure how to plot this in a graph:

```
Amy_dist = df1.loc['Amy'] / df1.sum(axis=1)
Andrew_dist = df2.loc['Andrew'] / df2.sum(axis=1)
```

Where: Amy_dist = 45.5% and Andrew_dist = 33.3%

I cannot figure out how to plot two bars comparing these two figures. Any advice would be appreciated!

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bar plot like this?

```
plt.bar(['Amy','Andrew'], [Amy_dist, Andrew_dist])
```

Answer (score 1):

- It will be more straightforward to combine the two sets of data, providing the combined `'ID'` names are unique, or create a new unique index before combining the dataframes.
- This way, no hard coding specific people, like `Amy_dist = df1.loc['Amy'] / df1.sum(axis=1)`, is required.
- In the combined dataframe, use `.groupby` to get the `sum` of the `'Count'` column per group, and then `divide` each `'Count'` by the sum for the group, to get the percent.

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Count': [5, 4, 2], 'ID': ['Amy', 'Chris', 'Gabe']}).set_index('ID')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Count': [2, 3, 1], 'ID': ['Andrew', 'Chloe', 'Georgia']}).set_index('ID')

# create a new column in each dataframe to identify where the data is from
df1['from'] = 1
df2['from'] = 2

# combine the dataframes
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

# create a norm column, which is the percent of the total based on the group
df['norm'] = df.Count.div(df.groupby('from').Count.transform('sum')).mul(100).round(2)

# display(df)
         Count  from   norm
ID                         
Amy          5     1  45.45
Chris        4     1  36.36
Gabe         2     1  18.18
Andrew       2     2  33.33
Chloe        3     2  50.00
Georgia      1     2  16.67
```

### Plot all the data

```py
df.plot(y='norm', kind='bar', grid=True, legend=False)
```

[image]

### Plot specific people

- Use `.loc` to specify individuals

```py
df.loc[['Amy', 'Andrew'], 'norm'].plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

### With `seaborn`

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot(data=df.reset_index(), x='ID', y='norm', hue='from', dodge=False)
```

[image]